# Django annotate conditional value

Tags: django, django-models, subquery, django-queryset

Lets say i have a model like this :

```
class modelA(models.model):
    name = models.Charfield()

class modelB(models.model):
    model_A = models.ForeignKey('modelA', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField()

class modelC(models.model):
    model_A = models.ForeignKey('modelA', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

How can i annotate the query so i can achieve something like this :

```
q = modelA.objects.all().annotate(value= # IF THERE IS modelC exist with related modelA THEN modelC.value ELSE modelB.value #)
```

Comment: A `modelA` could have multiple related `modelC` or `modelB`, which related value would you use when there are multiple related rows of the same model?

Comment: @IainShelvington, i dont understand your question. But what is working for me now is i both use different subquery and annotation for both modelB and C, and then i just check the conditional in the template if modelC is None i use modelB value. But i think there is another ways to achieve this only in View instead in Django Template.

Comment: If a `modelA` has two or more related `modelC` instances what value would you use?

Comment: @IainShelvington oh i see, i always use `first()` or `[:1]` just to get the value because there shouldnt be the case where `modelA` has two or more related `modelC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your query with the value from each related model, I used `Max` here to get the greatest from each relationship as it's not clear how you handle multiple related rows of the same model. Then use the database function [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Coalesce) to get the first non-null value from these previous annotations

```
modelA.objects.annotate(
    max_b=Max('modelb__value'), 
    max_c=Max('modelc__value')
).annotate(
    value=Coalesce('max_c', 'max_b')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

modelA can have multiple modelB and modelC objects, but since you are asking for the existence of either model, I will assume there can only be one of them, and take only the first value. First, you need to annotate the related values using `Subquery`, and after that, evaluate the `value` with sql switch-case:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Subquery, OuterRef, IntegerField


modelc_objects = modelC.objects.filter(model_A_id=OuterRef('pk'))
modelb_objects = modelB.objects.filter(model_A_id=OuterRef('pk'))

q = modelA.objects.all().annotate(
    c_value=Subquery(modelc_objects.values('value')[:1]),
    b_value=Subquery(modelb_objects.values('value')[:1]),
    value=Case(
        When(c_value__isnull=False, then=F('c_value')),
        When(b_value__isnull=False, then=F('b_value')),
        default=F('c_value'),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```